# MSGraph webhook subscribing to calendar

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api

So I am in the middle of rebuilding my application in Typescript with express.js and I want to add a subscription system in order to subscribe to resource mailboxes of a certain organization.
So I have seen several resources to access the calendar, but I'm worried it won't work for my case.

In my older version I am using /users/room@example.com/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-11-07T15:00:00Z&endDateTime=2023-11-07T23:59:59Z&$orderby=start/dateTime asc&$top=100.

This method gets every calendar instance so recurring bookings will return each instance separately instead of returning only the parent instance.

I am somewhat worried that webhooks won't be able to work for this as the dates are set for the duration of the webhook (which is 29, but I'll use 28 just to be sure) meaning that every time the subscription renews I have to update the dates of that resource.

I am required to use this as it would be too complex to properly process recurring booking instance changes as none of the other Calendar resources mentioned in the documentation is capable of returning recurring booking instances.

So does anybody know how I can properly create Microsoft Graph webhook Subscriptions to access not only regular booking instances but also recurring booking instances?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Billy

## UPDATE 1:

So the only method available to get bookings with webhooks is using /user/room@example.com/events.
But it doesn't work the way I want it...

When a booking is made it sends a create notification which is okay, but it also sends out several update notification right after it.
Which is basically a big risk since I still have to create it on my side, but they already want to update it.
Worst part is that when a booking is deleted it sends both delete and update notifications.
Which can cause issues as well like I had a delete notification and afterwards the update notification.
That would mean I have to mark it as deleted and if the update occurs for that booking to ignore it and only delete it later to ensure that no problems occurred.
Then there is the issue of the recurring booking because it only sends back the parent booking I am obligated to request a list of instances, and then I have to check which booking was updated based on the data stored which is making things kinda complex.

So now I'm wondering because webhooks will require this much work and basically generate a ton of requests, I might as well just use the regular calendar/calendarview endpoint and just use cron to regularly update the bookings.

Hence, the question does anyone know what the proper way is to approach this because I have no idea anymore...

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,